# How can I validate an openId id_token in javascript

Tags: angularjs, openid, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

I am using [identityserver v3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to authenticate my users in an angularjs based web application. therefor I request an id_token from the authorize endpoint that returns me what i want (id_token and access_token...). The [openid specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation) states that the id_token must be validated by the client. 
How can I achieve this in javascript. I could find some implementation in .net or java, but couldn't find any in javascript.

could someone provide me a library that does the job in javascript ?

the best would be  a method that takes the token as param and validate it : sthg like :

```
 mylib.validate(id_token);
```

some server offer an endpoint to validate it, but I really would like to validate it on the client

Comment: I just found this library from thinktecture and think it does what I want. But wonder if it's ok to use it even if we use another openid connect server :  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient/oidc.js

Comment: Does [this](http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/) help? I found it on openid connect website under list of [libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

we need to use **JSWS**

download the libraries from [here : JSJWS](https://github.com/kjur/jsjws/tags/). I’ve downloaded version 3.0.2.

in your *index.html*, you must reference the jws-3.0.js, the json-sans-eval.js file that you downloaded above
(json-sans-eval is located in [jsjws-3.0.2\ext] directory. (more info on it can be found here
json-sans-eval site)

if you run the code, you will get the following exception : **b64utohex is not defined**

you need to reference another library. in fact I found the related project **jsrsasign** having the required libraries.
you can download a release here : https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/tags/
I downloaded the version 4.7.0 and took out the jsrsasign-4.7.0-all-min.js file and added in referencing scripts.

Now you have all the necessary files to get it done using the following code :

```
function validateToken(id_token, cert) {
    var jws = new KJUR.jws.JWS();
    var result = 0;
    result = jws.verifyJWSByPemX509Cert(id_token, cert);
    if (result) {
        result = JSON.parse(jws.parsedJWS.payloadS);
    } else {
        result = 'unable to verify token';
    }
    return result;
}
```

the long story of this can be found [here](http://cedric-dumont.com/2015/03/31/openid-id_token-validation-in-javascript-an-angular-service/)

Comment: Validating id_token on client does not make sense. It should be on the server.